# How to eliminate coefficients from a sum

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, summation, normal-distribution

For given random values $$X_i \sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$ and $$\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma}=\tilde{X_i}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma),\,\mu\in\mathbb{R},\,\sigma>0$$ prove

$$\left(\frac{\left({\frac{{X_j}-\mu}{\sigma}}-{\frac{{X_k}-\mu}{\sigma}}\right)^2}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left({\frac{X_j-\mu}{\sigma}}-\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{\frac{X_j-\mu}{\sigma}}\right)\right)^2}\right)$$
$\overset{\text{d}}{=}$
$$\left(\frac{\left({X_j-X_k}\right)^2}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left({X_j}-\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{X_j}\right)\right)^2}\right)$$
So I have to eliminate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from the equation above.
I dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just factor out $1 / \sigma$. In the numerator and in the denomitator $1 / \sigma$ are in squared brackets. If you factor out them, the factor is in both cases $1 / \sigma ^2$. The factors can be cancelled. And the numerator becomes $X_j-\mu-(X_k-\mu)$. This gives $X_j-X_k$

Comment: Thanks, I have a problem to factor out the denumerator.
I got ${\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left({\frac{X_j-\mu}{\sigma}}-\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{\frac{X_j-\mu}{\sigma}}\right)\right)^2}\quad=\quad{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left({\frac{X_j-\mu}{\sigma}}-\frac{1}{\sigma}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{X_j}-n\mu\right)\right)^2}$

Comment: If we define $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{X_j}=\bar{X_n}$ we got $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{X_j-\mu}{\sigma}-\frac{\bar{X_n}-n\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2$. So we have the numerator $X_j-\mu-\left(\bar{X_n}-n\mu\right)$ what is $X_j-\bar{X_n}+(n-1)\mu$. Now?

Comment: $n\mu$ has to be divided by n, too. You only summed it up. $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mu=n\mu \ \color{blue}{\checkmark}$. Divided by n it is $\mu$